# Configuration of the receiver

Tags: http, wso2, complex-event-processing

I need create a receiver that process information HTTP/TEXT, for example:

```
curl -X POST -d Data:HolaMundo\r\Data2:Hello http://192.168.241.99:9763/endpoints/httpReceiverTEXTDSB --header "Content-Type:text/plain"
```

My STREAM has two attributes (DATA and DATA2), but in my HTTP I dont use (,), I need use (\r).

Is possible that my receiver runs with this configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to do with WSO2 CEP. You can map your string to event stream attributes by using regular expressions as explained in CEP sample 0006[1]. This[2] is the event receiver implemented in above sample with custom mapped fields with regular expressions.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/Sample+0006+-+Receiving+Custom+Text+Events+via+HTTP+Transport

[2] https://github.com/wso2/product-cep/blob/master/modules/samples/artifacts/0006/eventreceivers/httpReceiver.xml

Comment: Its perfect. All is runing without problems.  Data:(.*?)\n
Data2:(.*?)$